# What can be the regular expression to check either (abs1234567asd) or (1234567)

Tags: regex

There is one field for account number, it should contain a pattern like first and last three places should be characters and middle 7 should have numbers.

I wrote `([A-Z,a-z]{3}[0-9]{7}[A-Z,a-z]{3})` it is working fine but now I want to check it should be in above format or just 7 numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use an `OR` condition:

```
^[A-Z,a-z]{3}[0-9]{7}[A-Z,a-z]{3}$|^\d{7}$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/hX5xJ2/2

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to make the first & last parts optional. Now it will always match the 7 digits, optionally also matching the 3 chars either side.

`^([A-Za-z]{3})?[0-9]{7}([A-Za-z]{3})?$`

Comment: This will also match `abc1234567`

Comment: dont you think that `$` should be at the end and the `^` at the beginning ?

Comment: OP seemed to indicate it will only be one of 2 formats. That's how I interpreted it. @aelor Yes, typo.